# im trying to read the data from the image using pytesseract

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

i tried to open read the image using the pytesseract , however the code is not able to read it please check this photo im using for reading the text. [image]

below is my code:-

```
import cv2
import time
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:/Users/RTam/AppData/Local/Programs/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

def takescreenshot():
    
    path= (r'C:\Users\RTam\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos')
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(900,1000,1200,1100))
    
    im.save(path+'\\'+'ss.png')

img= cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\RTam\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos\ss3.png')

cv2.imshow('sample',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

sample_text= pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(sample_text)
```

the only output im getting is and empty space  please help

Comment: I get `|Analyzing` when I use the picture you posted using Tesseract version v4.0.0.20181030 on Windows. Any chance your file name is wrong?

Comment: no double checked it the file name is correct im using the tesseract version 5.0.1.20220118

Comment: i tried installing the same version as yours , but still no luck

Comment: @bfris if i return the out but of sample_text i get the out as ' \n\x0c'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I found the answer to my question.

However this code will not run properly in Spyder IDE, so we should make sure we have the latest tesseract version.

```
import cv2
import time
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:/Users/RTam/AppData/Local/Programs/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

def takescreenshot():
    
    path= (r'C:\Users\RTam\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos')
    im=ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(900,1000,1200,1100))
    
    im.save(path+'\\'+'ss.png')

img= cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\RTam\Desktop\python basics\web scraping\Pyautogui\photos\ss3.png')

def clerify_pic():
    img2 = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=2, fy=2)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thr = cv2.threshold(gry, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    
    
    return pytesseract.image_to_string(thr)
```